# Rails - Find all instances of all models with a certain attribute set to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

So lets say that I have a rails app with 3 models:
Posts
Products
Services
All of the above models have an attribute called featured, which is a boolean.
Is it possible to get all featured ( where featured is set to true ) posts, products, and services in 1 query?

Comment: why don't you make 3 queries and then append them all? 
Cause it's possible to make that query but it's a lot harder and you would end up with an array of relations which is hard to handle as well

Comment: Not without a join. These are all different models, so your resulting query is going to have a lot of columns. Are these models related by some sort of relationship? Can you be more specific on what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
[Post,Product,Service].each do |model|
  model.where(feature: true)
end
```